# Dynamically change second approver in workflow

Tags: workflow

We want to dynamically change the second approver in the approval workflow.  This should be decided based on a choice field.  The first approver will always be the same.

Ex 1: student picks choice 1.  Person A approves, then Person B approves because they are responsible for choice 1.

Ex 2: student picks choice 2.  Person A approves, then Person C approves because they are responsible for choice 2.

The ootb Approval workflow works fine except for the second serial approval.  So my problem is that the second serial approval depends on the choice field a student makes.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: I'm using the 2010 workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2010, you can use the `Start Approval Process` action in a Designer workflow. Create a variable that holds participant 2 (the user's display name), and use that variable in the approval process. Click on the first link to customize the actions of individual tasks. Click on the last link to set participants, name the task, and enter instructions that will be included in notification emails. Additionally, you might want to change a couple variable from default. If you want the workflow to stop on a reject or when the item is changed, you have to set the `CancelonRejection` and/or `CancelonChange` variables to yes before you start the approval step.

[image]

It takes a bit of cleaning up to get the custom approval action to behave exactly how you want, but it allows for more customization and path flexibility compared to the OOTB approval workflows.